# Why is this webgl code not drawing to the canvas?

Tags: webgl, twgl.js

I am writing what should be a simple wrapper around `twgl` so that I can work on shaders with a react UX. Why does this simple program not draw pixels on the Framebuffer?

Here is the wrapper class:

```js
import * as twgl from 'twgl.js'

export class WGL {
  image: any;
  texture: any;
  gl: WebGLRenderingContext;

  constructor(_gl: WebGLRenderingContext) {
    this.gl = _gl;

    var ext = this.gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
    if (!ext) {
      alert('requires OES_texture_float');
    }
  }

  async loadImage(src: string) {
    const gl = this.gl;

    const _this = this;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('ct', gl, this.gl);
      twgl.createTexture(
        gl,
        {
          src,
          min: gl.NEAREST,
          mag: gl.NEAREST,
          wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
          crossOrigin: '',
        },
        (err: Error, texture: any, image: any) => {
          if (err) return reject(err);

          _this.image = image;
          _this.texture = texture;

          resolve({ image });
        }
      );
    });
  }

  async process() {
    const { gl, image, texture } = this;

    sampleTexture(gl, texture);

    const pi = await twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [
      vertex_shader_src,
      fragment_shader_src,
    ]);

    const quadBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);

    gl.useProgram(pi.program);

    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, pi, quadBufferInfo);

    // image to hold the result
    const targetFbi = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(
      gl,
      [
        {
          type: gl.FLOAT,
          min: gl.NEAREST,
          mag: gl.NEAREST,
          wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
        },
      ],
      image.width,
      image.height
    );
    if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
      alert("can't render to floating point texture");
    }

    twgl.setUniforms(pi, {
      u_texture: texture,
    });

    twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, targetFbi);

    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, quadBufferInfo);

    sampleTexture(gl, targetFbi);
  }
}
```

Here is the react app:

```js
export function App() {
  const outputRef = useRef();

  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState(DEFAULT_IMAGE);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!outputRef.current || !imageSrc) return;

    var gl = outputRef.current.getContext('webgl');
    const wgl = new WGL(gl);

    wgl.loadImage(imageSrc).then(({ image }) => {
      wgl.process();
    });
  }, [outputRef, imageSrc]);

  return (
    <>
      <span>
        <canvas ref={outputRef} width="256" height="256"></canvas>
      </span>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have been using a `sampleTexture()` function to look at pixel values. The first call to `sampleTexture()` shows good pixel values from the given image. The second call should show modified versions of those pixels but shows zeroes. (If I bind to `null` and draw to the canvas, it's all black.)

```js
export const sampleTexture = (
  gl: WebGLRenderingContext,
  texture: WebGLTexture,
  size = 10
) => {
  console.log('sampleTexture');
  var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    texture,
    0
  );
  if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) == gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    var pixels = new Uint8Array(size * size * 4);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, size, size, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    console.log(pixels); // Uint8Array
  }
};
```

I have verified that these shaders work elsewhere:

```c
//vertex
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {

   gl_Position = vec4(position.x, -position.y, 0, 1);

   v_texCoord = texcoord;
}

// fragment
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
  precision highp float;
#else
  precision mediump float;
#endif

// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {

   vec4 pixel = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);

   gl_FragColor = vec4(pixel.r, pixel.g, 0, 1);
}
```

UPDATE:
The problem was the way I brought in `twgl.js`. I was importing `twgl.js` into the WGL source file and bundling with webpack. If I use an html script tag for `twgl.js` everything works as expected. How can I bundle `twgl.js` in a way that doesn't change how it works?